# Convert a non-standardized test data into a standard report for every student taking test of similar difficulty more than once.

Tags: statistics

**Context :**

> Suppose that there are 5 sets of exams being conducted, each for the
> same purpose. Since they are being conducted over a period of 5 days,
> the papers are different but a student can appear at most once. The
> number of students appearing on each day is different and so is the
> difficulty of the paper depending on the student.

**Questions :**

1. Given the test reports of every student, how would you scale the scores (ie, generate the test report of each student) as if every student is writes the same question paper?
2. Now suppose a subset (possibly *improper*) of these students take the test (which is conducted over a period of 5 days and has the "same" difficulty but a student can appear at most once) again. Given their test reports, how would you find the score of each student if we were to consider his/her best score in the two tests (upon proper scaling) and generate a single final test report?

In [2] above, the best score possibly also requires a proper scaling. **I am essentially trying to see how we can solve [2]. But that requires us to solve [1]** and this is precisely why it looks like a 2-part question (which is against the rules of Stack, if I am not mistaken). I am trying to use the non-standardized test data for a *very large* (hypothetically, so the misc. dependence factors are reduced) pool of students from the same place into a standardized report for every student.

Please feel free to suggest or edit the topic and add more suitable tags. I do not have a very strong grasp of the subject.

Comment: If "The papers are meant to have different levels of difficulty", are students assigned papers depending on the students' individual skills?

Comment: @Henry The papers are not "meant" to have different levels of difficulty, they rather *will* (involuntarily, if that makes more sense) have different levels of difficulty depending on the student. The wording is incorrect, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @oldsailorpopoye First of all, comments don't actually bump questions on Stack Exchange; second of all, please don't try and bump questions for the sake of bumping them. Once 48 hours have passed, you'll be able to put a bounty on this question to attract more attention.

Comment: 1)Do the students get to chose on which day do they take the test or re they assigned a testing day at random? 2) Are students who wrote the test earlier likely to talk to those who have not yet appeared about how it went and what the questions were?

Comment: I think that the question should be migrated to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GradaGukovic 1) They are assigned at random, but does that really matter? You do not have any detail of the students initially. 2) The students might talk, but in this regard, we assume that one has negligible to no advantage over another since the papers in the previous years were similar and 5 different papers were given on 5 different days so there's no malpractice. This condition need not be incorporated to generate the final test report.

Comment: [Here is the link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508568/convert-a-non-standardized-test-data-into-a-standard-report-for-every-student-ta) to the same question posted on Cross Validated (stats.SE).

Comment: Do you have any objective way to estimate the "difficulty" of the paper given to each particular student? I mean, how do you plan to distinguish between students failing because they lack the necessary knowledge and students failing because the exam is hard if each student has his own version of the test and all you see is the test score? Or are there just a few versions, each given to a large number of students? (then the days do not matter much but the versions do)

Answer (score 1):

First, determine if there is a significant difference between exams.  Fit a Generalized Linear Model (GLM) with an appropriate link function $g$ for your exam.  Perhaps this is a Beta regression problem if the scores are on the 0-100% scale.

$$g(Y_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i$$

where $x_i$ is a categorical variable for the exam (so it is really four variables)

Second, if the overall Likliehood Ratio Test for the model is significant, then there are at least two exams that are different.

Third, if there is a significant exam effect, then scale the exams by the mean exam score for that group so that the mean translates to a particular target score (80%).

Something like this in `R`:

````
set.seed(123454)
# number of students
N <- 100
# randomly select a test
x <- sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), size = N, replace = TRUE)
# randomly create a score for each student
y <- ifelse(x == "A", rbeta(N, 3, 2), ifelse(
  x == "B", rbeta(N, 4, 2), ifelse(
    x == "C", rbeta(N, 5, 2), ifelse(
      x == "D", rbeta(N, 6, 2), ifelse(
        x == "E", rbeta(N, 7, 2), NA)
      )
    )
  )
)

hist(y, breaks = 10)

# fit a simple quasibinomial model with a logit link
#   better to do a beta regression here, but quasibinomial is illustrative
lm1 <- glm(y ~ x, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))
lm2 <- glm(y ~ 1, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))

anova(lm1, lm2, test = "LRT")

# therefore there are at least two exams that are different

# now scale
mean_values <- by(y, x, mean)
target_mean <- 0.8

# one method of normalizing so that no one goes over 100%
new_scores <- 1 - c((1-y) / (1-mean_values[x]) * (1-target_mean))
mean(new_scores)
by(new_scores, x, mean)
hist(new_scores, breaks = 10)

```
````

Comment: Credit to https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/212798/r-carnell for the answer. I know I could have flagged this question as duplicate but this was a bounty question so i think flagging bounty question is wrong